# Where are all these errors coming from?

Tags: tables, beamer, errors

With the following document, I get a lot of errors around line 38. I can't tell where these come from, but the resulting output looks fine. For the sake of good practice, what am I doing wrong here?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}

\title{Why Duodecimal is Better than Decimal\\
(Yes, really.)}
\author{Alex Stubbins}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\frame{\titlepage}

\section{Introduction}
\subsection{}
\frame{
\frametitle{What is duodecimal?}
Duodecimal, less commonly referred to as dozenal, is a number system that has a base of twelve, whereas our standard number system, decimal, has a base of twelve.
}
\frame
{
\frametitle{Fractions}\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    Fraction       & Base-12                                 & Base-10             \\ \hline
    $\frac{1}{2}$  & 0.6                                     & 0.5                 \\ \hline
    $\frac{1}{3}$  & 0.4                                     & 0.\overline{33}     \\ \hline
    $\frac{1}{4}$  & 0.3                                     & 0.25                \\ \hline
    $\frac{1}{5}$  & 0.\overline{24972497}~or~$\approx$~0.25 & 0.2                 \\ \hline
    $\frac{1}{6}$  & 0.2                                     & 0.1                 \\ \hline
    $\frac{1}{7}$  & 0.\overline{186A35}                     & 0.\overline{142857} \\ \hline
    $\frac{1}{8}$  & 0.16                                    & 0.125               \\ \hline
    $\frac{1}{9}$  & 0.14                                    & 0.\overline{1}      \\ \hline
    $\frac{1}{10}$ & 0.\overline{12497}                      & 0.1                 \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
}
\end{document}
```

The resulting errors are:

Log can be seen [here](https://raw.github.com/gist/4122789/61f9a0a6bfe6aedec5bf51c051e6d72cea6cb9f8/gistfile1.txt)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436), and thanks for providing a compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since this question is about "learning", here are some suggestions:

- `\overline` requires math mode, so you need to brace it with `$...$`;
- Tables look awesome when using the [`booktabs` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs);
- Consider using the environment form of `frame`, so `\begin{frame}...\end{frame}` rather than `\frame{...}`;
- Since you're using predominantly math in the `tabular`, rather use an `array` environment. This requires non-math elements to be in text mode. I've used `\textrm` below, although you might consider using something like `\textsf` since the document style is written in a sans-serif font; and
- There's no requirement to use a `table` (floating) environment in a presentation, or anywhere for that matter, if you don't have an accompanying caption. So, rather avoid it here.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}% http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
\usepackage{beamerthemesplit,booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs

\title{Why Duodecimal is Better than Decimal\\
  (Yes, really.)}
\author{Alex Stubbins}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\frame{\titlepage}

\section{Introduction}
\subsection{}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{What is duodecimal?}
Duodecimal, less commonly referred to as dozenal, is a number system that has a base of twelve, whereas our standard number system, decimal, has a base of twelve.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Fractions}

\[
  \begin{array}{ccc}
    \toprule
    \textrm{Fraction} & \textrm{Base-12}                          & \textrm{Base-10}    \\
    \midrule
    \frac{1}{ 2} & 0.6                                            & 0.5                 \\
    \frac{1}{ 3} & 0.4                                            & 0.\overline{33}     \\
    \frac{1}{ 4} & 0.3                                            & 0.25                \\
    \frac{1}{ 5} & 0.\overline{24972497}~\textrm{or}~\approx 0.25 & 0.2                 \\
    \frac{1}{ 6} & 0.2                                            & 0.1                 \\
    \frac{1}{ 7} & 0.\overline{186A35}                            & 0.\overline{142857} \\
    \frac{1}{ 8} & 0.16                                           & 0.125               \\
    \frac{1}{ 9} & 0.14                                           & 0.\overline{1}      \\
    \frac{1}{10} & 0.\overline{12497}                             & 0.1                 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{array}
\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

The `\overline{}` need to be used in math mode.

Furthermore, numbers should usually be in math mode (important if you have negative numbers), and since most of our table has numerical content you could just use the `array` environment and use `\text{}` to go out of math mode for the titles. I have adjusted the code below to use `array`:

[image]

---

### Code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}

\title{Why Duodecimal is Better than Decimal\\
(Yes, really.)}
\author{Alex Stubbins}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\frame{\titlepage}

\section{Introduction}
\subsection{}
\frame{
\frametitle{What is duodecimal?}
Duodecimal, less commonly referred to as dozenal, is a number system that has a base of twelve, whereas our standard number system, decimal, has a base of twelve.
}
\frame
{
\frametitle{Fractions}\begin{table}
$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \text{Fraction} & \text{Base-12}                       & \text{Base-10}      \\ \hline
    \frac{1}{2}  & 0.6                                     & 0.5                 \\ \hline
    \frac{1}{3}  & 0.4                                     & 0.\overline{33}     \\ \hline
    \frac{1}{4}  & 0.3                                     & 0.25                \\ \hline
    \frac{1}{5}  & 0.\overline{24972497}~\text{or}~\approx~0.25 & 0.2            \\ \hline
    \frac{1}{6}  & 0.2                                     & 0.1                 \\ \hline
    \frac{1}{7}  & 0.\overline{186A35}                     & 0.\overline{142857} \\ \hline
    \frac{1}{8}  & 0.16                                    & 0.125               \\ \hline
    \frac{1}{9}  & 0.14                                    & 0.\overline{1}      \\ \hline
    \frac{1}{10} & 0.\overline{12497}                      & 0.1                 \\
    \hline
\end{array}$
\end{table}
}
\end{document}
```